# How to set mysqli_result::num_rows

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, hhvm

For mocking purposes, I extended the mysqli_result class:

```
class MysqliResultMock extends mysqli_result {
   ...
}
```

Now, I need to override what it returns for its member called 'num_rows', but unfortunately with $this->num_rows = 123; it's simply not settable (I get a fatal error for writing this line:

```
Fatal error: Cannot directly set the property MysqliResultMock::$num_rows in DbTest.php on line 13)
```

Can it be done somehow?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I figured out the answer.

You just need to add the public $num_rows; line to the class, explicitly, to make it writable. Like this:

class result extends mysqli_result {

```
public $num_rows;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->num_rows = 6;
```

...

then you can call mysql_num_rows() on an instance and it will return the given num_rows properly.